# Can i use angular-material with cordova?

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I intend to create a [Material design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html) based App for Android and Windows.Generally I use [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) with [Ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/) for development.

In that combo can I add the css and js file of [Angular-material](https://material.angularjs.org/#/) and create an app with Material Design ?

Comment: yes, you can add any JS or CSS you would like to any project

Comment: No my question is will cordova support all the features of 
Angular-material ? And will there any lagging or problems in the app generated ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, angular material works with Cordova. I have tried basic application with AngularJS, Angular Material and Cordova. And this combination works. Angular material is still in development. I am facing few performance bottle necks. This may be one aspect need to think for time being.

Comment: There are some bugs regarding ng-click and angular material version 0.7.1 to 0.8.x. Other than that, this combinations works really well.

Comment: it's OK now... https://github.com/angular/material/blob/v0.11.2/CHANGELOG.md#0112-2015-10-01

Answer (score 4):

Ionic Framework doesn't play well along with Angular Material.

But you can use AngularJs + Cordova + AngularMaterial and it will work like a charm.


If you do want a seed to start, you can look to this one:

https://github.com/mario-aleo/cordova-angular-angularMaterial-seed

Comment: I just looked at your github repo. This looks like EXACTLY what i need. It is VERY WELL EXPLAINED. Thanks A LOT!

Comment: I have just used this seed to produce a running app on my tablet. Not only is the github repo documentation GREAT, but the code in the seed is SUPERBLY READABLE. I will learn A LOT from using your code, Mario. Thanks again.

Comment: @MarioAleo From the performance perspective, how is that comapring to ionic or onsen-ui if you have used before

Comment: Sorry @RezaRahmati, I'm not sure about it, I did try ionic for a short time, but I couldn't keep feeling like I was stuck with the ionic set of components... but I didn't found difference about the performance, especially if you pay attention to performance details about the construction of your controllers or components.

Answer (score 2):

You should not have any issues using Material Design in the same way that you've been using Ionic with Cordova.

In fact, the Ionic team was directly involved in the creation of Material Design.  Check out this video for an overview of Material Design by Max Lynch, the co-creator of Ionic.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2qiyhkQVyxE&list=UUEGUP3TJJfMsEM_1y8iviSQ

Answer (score 0):

I've had some problems with cordova compared to straight mobile chrome.  Some element don't align right and I think it has to do with the heavy use of flex.  I'm still investigating but I'm pretty sure the version of webview my not support it completely.  I know that older android versions won't at all. I'll update this if I know more or if anyone else has input on this post here.

Comment: You can try using Crosswalk on android to get the webview up to a recent version of chromium - https://www.crosswalk-project.org/

Answer (score 0):

I am using this seed : https://github.com/mario-aleo/cordova-angular-angularMaterial-seed

Overall feeling is really great. I am testing elements of material design in the app. Problems that I can see so far is dialog. It opens kinda laggy a bit.